# How to create a count for modules

Tags: php, html, count, counter

So I have created a replica of a site. It has four Topics shown like this;

### Topic 1

### Topic 2

### Topic 3

### Topic 4

How do I create a count where it only counts the number of topics I have in total which is 4.
I am very new at coding and am trying to learn the basics on my own but don't understand.
Thank you.